# Is there a web based SVN viewer/browser that can let you browse any repository that is available online?

Tags: web-services, svn, version-control

I don't want to install a single thing. There must be a web based viewer somewhere! I'm having a hard time finding such a thing in google.

There must be somewhere online where I can simply paste "svn://nex-3.com/gtk-themes" and it will let me browse the contents of the repository (assuming the repo exists and is publicly viewable).

EDIT: I guess I can just use any browser's directory tree browser. hehe

Comment: cant you just point your browser to the repo? http://server/svn/repo

Comment: @mxmissile: Only if they're using WebDav instead of svn or svn+ssh.

Comment: Well let's say i go to school, open up a web service that let's me view my repo (be it git, svn, bzr, etc). It'd be great to be able to paste code into the service, press "commit", and then it updates my repo (the repo being hosted anywhere, not with the service)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I can just use any browser's directory tree browser. hehe

Answer (score 2):

To access svn via http, you could configure it with apache using mod_dav.
I know that you have to install something, but it is what I would use.

Comment: I can't install anything at school, and if I could, the computers are re-imaged every day so i'd have to install every day... or if i leave the room and come back to a different computer then i'd have to re-install... There must be a website that can access a GIT, SVN, or BZR

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your own SVN installed locally or are you looking for a hosted SVN solution?

If you're looking for a hosted solution with http access, [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) is great.

Comment: I jsut want to access my local repo (be it GIT, SVN, BZR, or whatever) from a browsers. For example, a website where you can type in svn://whatever.com/svn and then see your repo would be cool.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Firefox` add-on called [Tortoise SVN Menu](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3416/?src=api) but it requires [Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) client to be installed as well.